# how would you disable a button till the user navigates through prior buttons?

Tags: android, button

how would you disable a button until a user click on the buttons prior to it. One of the buttons has there bio info which is set in preferences. So I can't have them continue until they read the directions and fill there bio.

Answer (score 1):

Disable it in the layout file and only activate it in the activity (onCreate()/onResume()) when the needed info is filled in

Answer (score 1):

In `onClick()` for the button you want to press first call `setClickable(boolean)` for the button you would like to activate.

Also, if you want the button to start as being unclickable you should set the clickable attribute in your xml to false as well

```
<Button
android:clickable="false"
```

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make a state button for this task? Or have a state object that controls the button